# printer zebra calibration Issue

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I alternately use 2 different label type and size, I have a zd421 Zebra Printer and when changing the labels it execute the media calibration automaticly to the rigth size of label, but it prints 3-5 blank label each time we change paper, is there any possibility to disable printing extra blank label during calibration? is it possible to disable the media calibration? I apreciate you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your printer has a display, you can change this in the tools ("power up action" and "head close action") menu otherwise you can use the ^MF ZPL command.

Have a look [here](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/languages/zpl/printers-zpl-language-mf-command) to see how you can set the automatic action when you close the printer lid and when you power on the printer and [here](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/languages/printers-sending-commands-using-zebra-setup-utilities) you can see how to send the commands to the printer.

But in few words, if you want to disable the calibration at all, you've to send the following commands

```
^XA
^MFN,N
~JUS
^XZ
```